# Storbinary Format Strings Python3 FTPLib

Tags: python, database, string, python-3.x, ftplib

```
marlin=open(bacteria,'rb')
session.storbinary('STOR bacteria.png',open(bacteria,'rb'))
```

So basically I want to change the name bacteria.png each time I run the script. I want to make it the time the script is ran("10:00pm.png").

```
bacteria=time.time()
bacteria=str(bacteria)+".png"
```

How would I use format strings in storbinary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import time

# Get the current time and format as a string
timestring = time.strftime('%H:%M%p', time.gmtime()).lower()
# Create a format string for the STOR command
stor_format = 'STOR {}.png'
# Format the format string with the timestring
session.storbinary(stor_format.format(timestring), open(bacteria,'rb'))
```

[`time.gmtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.gmtime) gets the UTC time - use [`time.localtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.localtime) if you prefer using local time.

[`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.strftime) formats the time as a string, using the provided format.  The format string `'%H:%S%p'` formats the time as two-digit hours and minutes, separated by a colon and followed by 'AM' or 'PM'.  Calling `.lower()` on the result of `time.strftime()` converts 'AM' or 'PM' to lower case: 'am' or 'pm'.

By replacing the word 'bacteria' in the STOR command with the `'{}'` placeholder you can create the STOR command that you want.

```
>>> time_string = time.strftime('%H:%M%p', time.gmtime()).lower()
>>> print(time_string)
12:54pm
>> stor_format = 'STOR {}.png'
>>> stor_format.format(time_string)
'STOR 12:54pm.png'
```